# concatenar uma variavel para chamar uma imagem em php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Olá, estou tentando chamar uma imagem direto de uma pasta criada dinamicamente com php porem o codigo me retorna esse erro:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Painel de controle\produtos.php on line 103

aqui está o codigo utilizado:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conn_prod.php';
include 'processa_img.php';

$tema = mysqli_query($conn_prod,"SELECT * FROM necessaires;");

$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn_prod, "SELECT * FROM necessaires WHERE tema");
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
    # code...
    $tema = $line['imagem'];
    $nome_image = $lina['tema']; 
};
```

?>

corpo do documento

Mais PHP

```
<div class="log_prods"> 
<div class="corpo_log">
<?php

//RECEBER O NUMERO DA PAGINA
    $pagina_atual   =   filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pagina');

     $pagina = (!empty($pagina_atual))  ?  $pagina_atual : 1;

//SETAR A QUANTIDADE DE ITENS POR PAGINA
     $quant_result_pg = 5;

//CALCULAR O INICIO DA VISUALIZAÇÃO
     $inicio = ($quant_result_pg * $pagina) - $quant_result_pg;



    $pegar_result = "SELECT * FROM necessaires LIMIT $inicio, $quant_result_pg";
    $result_produtos = mysqli_query($conn_prod, $pegar_result);

        while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_produtos)) {
            # code...
            echo "<section><span>Tema :</span>" . $row_produto['tema'] . "<br>
                  <span>ID :</span>" . $row_produto['id_nec'] . "<div class='cont_img-prod'><img src='upload/$tema/$nome_image'></div></section><hr>";
        };
        ?>
        <?php

//  PAGINAÇÃO - SOMAR A QUANTIDADE DE USUARIOS
    $result_pg = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_result FROM necessaires";
    $resultado_pg = mysqli_query($conn_prod, $result_pg);
    $row_pg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_pg);
    //echo $row_pg['num_result'];

//QUANTIDADE DE PAGINAS

    $quantidade_pg = ceil($row_pg['num_result'] / $quant_result_pg);
    ?>
</div>
    <div class="cont_setas"><div class="setas_">
    <?php

//LIMITAR OS LINKS ANTES E DEPOIS
    $max_links = 1;
    echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=1'><i class='pag_pri fas fa-angle-double-left'></i></a>";

        for ($pag_ant = $pagina - $max_links; $pag_ant <= $pagina - 1; $pag_ant ++) { 
            # code...
            if ($pag_ant >= 1){

                echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=$pag_ant'>$pag_ant</a>";
            }
        }

    echo "$pagina";

    for($pag_dep = $pagina + 1; $pag_dep <= $pagina + $max_links; $pag_dep ++){

                if ($pag_dep <= $quantidade_pg) {
                    # code...
                    echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=$pag_dep'>$pag_dep</a>";
                }
    }

    echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=$quantidade_pg'><i class='pag_ult fas fa-angle-double-right'></i></a>";
?>
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RESOLUÇÃO

Variável $tema está sendo sobrescrita no primeiro bloco de código.

---

Quebre as strings para inserir as variaveis. Seu codigo está assim:

```
echo "<section>"
 . "<span>Tema :</span>" . $row_produto['tema'] . "<br>"
 . "<span>ID :</span>" . $row_produto['id_nec']
 . "<div class = 'cont_img-prod'>"
 . " <img src = 'upload/$tema/$nome_image'>"
 . " </div>"
 . " </section>"
 . " <hr>";
```

Na tag *img* o url dela está tudo dentro da String. Deixando-o assim:

```
echo "<section>"
 . "<span>Tema :</span>" . $row_produto['tema'] . "<br>"
 . "<span>ID :</span>" . $row_produto['id_nec']
 . "<div class = 'cont_img-prod'>"
 . " <img src = 'upload/$tema/$nome_image'>"
 . " </div>"
 . " </section>"
 . " <hr>";
```

Outra dica, para ficar mais facil de formatar o HTML dentro de um laço ou if, você pode "quebrar" o PHP ao invés de dar echo em um monte de coisa.

De assim:

```
while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_produtos)) {
        # code...
        echo "<section><span>Tema :</span>" . $row_produto['tema'] . "<br>
              <span>ID :</span>" . $row_produto['id_nec'] . "<div class='cont_img-prod'><img src='upload/$tema/$nome_image'></div></section><hr>";
    };
```

Para:

```
while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_produtos)) {
 ?>
       <section>
             <span>Tema :</span>  <?=$row_produto['tema'];?> <br>
             <span>ID :</span> <?=$row_produto['id_nec'];?> 
             <div class='cont_img-prod'>
                  <img src='upload/<?= $tema."/".$nome_image;?>'>
             </div>
       </section>
   <hr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: eu agradeço a ajuda mas o codigo continua com o mesmo problema porem agora passou para a linha 106

Comment: O codigo está completo? Qual a linha 106 que ele está dando problema? Pode ser um erro no comando SQL

Comment: a linha é essa: " <img src = 'upload/$tema/$nome_image'>"   não nada de errado por isso acho que seja concatenização que este errada

Comment: Naquele primeiro bloco de codigo você tem $tema = mysqli_query($conn_prod,"SELECT * FROM necessaires;"); e depois você sobrescreve essa variável.  Nao pode ser isso?

Comment: nossa era isso mesmo kkk Muito obrigado